# Saving a file name as a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I need a way to save the name of a file into a variable, so that after I delete that file, I can create a new file with the same name as the original. How can I do that?

for example, I take in a file and store it as var1 and another as var2 using

```
file=$var1
file=$var2
```

later in my code, I need to delete var2 and create a link to var1 with the same name as the original var2. The command:

```
rm var2
ln var1 var2
```

creates an error message
I think I need to create a temporary variable that holds just the name of the file var2, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This question (and your other two recent ones) clearly show that you really need to get a shell scripting book and not try to play "guess the syntax" or "ask SO when that fails." IMHO, helping you further by giving you the answers will really be a disservice to you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need a "$" sign:

```
# Set a variable
myvar=moose

# Get the contents of a variable
echo $myvar  # Prints "moose"
```

In your case:

```
var1=myfirstfile
var2=mysecondfile
rm $var2
ln $var1 $var2
```

Comment: This doesnt work because if I dont declare the variables with a $, then I cant process the files within my code

Answer (score 1):

Which shell are you using? What OS?

With Linux and BASH it would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set variable $var1, it will contain a string - 'file':
var1='file'

# Set variable $var2, it will contain a string - 'another_file':
var2='another_file'

# Run 'rm' command with an argument - a variable $var1
# So it's like running a command "rm file"
rm $var1

# Run 'ln' command with $var1 and $var2 as arguments
# So it's like running a command "ln file another_file"
ln $var1 $var2
```

But in Mac OS X `ln` has different syntax and you have to switch arguments in `ln`:

```
ln $var2 $var1
```

**Edit:** Also, your problem may be that you use file path with spaces in it, so bash shows `"no such file or directory"` errors. 
It can't find the file because of `rm`'s syntax. For example:

```
var1='long named file'
rm $var1
```

This script does run a command `"rm long named file"`, which, in turn, deletes three files - `long`, `named` and `file`.
Then that would do the thing for you:

```
rm "$var1"
ln "$var1" "$var2"
```

Comment: I'm using bash. If I declare the variables like you did with 'file' , I cant process the file in my code..

Comment: @user1161080 Can you elaborate, please? What's the exact problem with processing? Any warnings/errors while running the script?

Comment: @user1161080 I've edited the answer. In short, try using `rm "$var1"` and `ln "$var1" "$var2"` instead.

Comment: The problem is that using your method, when I first store the incoming file as a variable, if I write var1='file' , it wont let me do work on the file. I only can do work on it if I do var1 = $file.

Comment: @user1161080 But then it's looking like `$file` is another variable you've set earlier. If you first declare `$file` and `$another` variables, and then declare `$var1` and `$var2` and make them equal `$file` and `$another` respectively, it doesn't make sense. How do you store the incoming files (that you need to `rm` and `ln` later), as a filename/path? In what variables? How do you declare those variables?